# Getting logged in identities with an id token via Xamarin's Auth0.SDK

Tags: xamarin, auth0

The `Auth0User` object returned from `LoginAsync()` contains a list of the logged in identities.

But how do I get this upon without seeing the login dialog LoginAsync presents - I'd just like to use the id token saved from the previous login?

There seems to be a tokeninfo endpoint for this, but Xamarin's Auth0.SDK seems to eliminate dealing with REST - so feel like I'm missing something.

Answer (score 1):

If the user has already logged in, you can do a refresh:

```
var client = new Auth0.SDK.Auth0Client ("XXXXXXX.auth0.com", "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
await client.RefreshToken();
Console.Writeline(client.CurrentUser);
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately CurrentUser just gets updated with the new id token - not the profile (identities) or even the Auth0AccessToken. Looking at the source code for RefreshToken I also confirm that unlike LoginAsync(), the identities aren't added to CurrentUser.

Comment: Anyone who could update the solution in 2018? I'm stuck in refreshing the token in Xamarin app using Auth0 sdk and custom login page lock v11